# Pro vs Con on using export to JPEG or JP2000 files for large imagery files

Tags: arcgis-desktop, envi, erdas-imagine, jpg, jpeg-2000

What is the preference among GIS Specialist and Remote Sensing Specialist using the JPEG vs JP2000.

Yes, I am aware of other compressed files such as ECW or MrSID...

I am more of concern of how to add them to ArcMap or ENVI or ERDAS because it can take some time for these software to load them.

Currently, I have ArcGIS 10.1, ENVI 5.0 (plan on to upgrade to 5.1), and ERDAS 2010.

Comment: When you say JPEG, do you mean a .jpg file or another format (e.g. a tiff) with JPEG compression?

Comment: @Luke  Yes I mean .jpg file

Comment: both are lossy compression, so what kind of data do you plan to use it for ?

Comment: Well everyone knows that NAIP uses mrsid so it can be very difficult to subset some and then save them to either JPEG or JP2000.I will have to do subset from each county and then later mosaic them and export to either format.

Comment: I know most of you probably did smaller imagery and save them to either format should work.

Comment: I think it is almost always best to respond to requests for clarifications by editing your question.

Answer (score 3):

JPEG2000 Pros:

- Better compression than JPEG
- Supports both lossy and lossless compression, JPEG is lossy only
- Supports any number of bands, JPEG only supports 3 bands
- Supports more datatypes (including floating point), JPEG only supports 8 bit (byte) data
- Internal precomputed multiresolution representation (aka pyramids)

JPEG2000 Cons:

- Limited opensource support, the Jasper library can only handle small images and both it and OpenJPEG are horrendously slow. The only real options for JPEG2000 compression are proprietary software.

Comment: If I *have* to pick betwen those two (JPEG/JPEG2000) then JPEG2000 is the way to go for exactly the reasons Luke stated. ECW is considerably better for 8bit and now supports greyscale, RGB and RGBA. However ECW is a licensed compression (costs money) and some of the best JP2K compressors are also licensed... JPEG is always free. From a user point-of-view JP2K is slightly slower to render than JPEG (much slower than ECW) and JP2K causes memory problems in older versions of ArcGis (and other sofware) due to a bad dll with a memory leak. GDAL doesn't have this problem.

Comment: I'd have to agree with you on loading JP2K to ArcMap it take almost forever. I wonder how would you keep the bands if you compressed to ECW ? @MichaelMiles-Stimson

Comment: ECW is limited to 8 bit and only 1, 3 or 4 bands (greyscale, RGB and RGBA). Generally if I have more than 3 data bands I go with LZW/Deflate Tiff, mostly I deal with RGB or RGBA which suits ECW... I would take a larger file size over mucking up data with multiband for interpretation but can live with a bit of pixel value change with heads-up digitizing off orthophotography.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson ECW v3 supports UInt16 multiband data. It's not backwards compatible with earlier versions of the SDK (<=4.x) though so ArcGIS can't read it (as at ArcGIS 10.2.2).

Comment: That's interesting, but it's only supported by ERDAS at the moment.. future releases of ArcGis, GDAL etc.. may support it, then it should be more widely received.

Comment: Where would one obtain SDK v5? I've tried the ERDAS site and couldn't find it (for free), not that I have ECW v3 images that specifically require it but who knows what the future holds - an ounce of preparation is worth a pound of cure.

Comment: Ta. I'm downloading that now. Does it integrate seamlessly with GDAL or do you need to edit system paths/registry settings?

Comment: Depends... OSGEO4W/GISInternal binaries include the desktop R/O binaries (v5.0). If you want v5.1, you have to compile it in yourself (I have a ticket in to GISInternal to update the SDK).

Comment: I would add a few points: 1) For decompressing any image data out of JPEG the whole image must be decompressed which makes it unusable for really big geospatial images. 2) JPEG2000 compression can be done in thousands of different ways. Have a look at http://kakadusoftware.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/Usage_Examples.txt. It is oversimplified to say that JPEG2000 is good/bad without describing what has been studied: imagery, parameters, and software. 3) Flexibility and implementations with different weak/strong points is hard for users; a good recipe for one SDK may be a bad one for another.

Comment: @user30184 that's useful information, would you consider adding as an answer so it doesn't get lost in the comments?